# how to insert array values in the database that are called in the class as an object in php

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

i need to store the array value that are called in the class as an object in the database.
coding

```
<?php
echo "BEST SELECTED POPULATION";
debug(GA::select($ga->population,'total',3)); //The best
$asma[]=GA::select($ga->population,'total',3); //The best
}
print_r($asma);
?>
```

`$array1` is the array in which i get the output value,this array is dynamic that is the number of values increases in it depend on the user input.

```
 <?php
    include('config.php');
    //database connection
    //query
    $new_array = array($asma);

    foreach($new_array as $key => $value) {

       foreach ( $value as $ind => $data ) {
          /*
          You now have access to field values like this
           $data['Voltage']
           $data['Number']
           $data['Duration']
          */

          // query makes no sense 3 fields mentioned and 4 parameters given???
          // you will have to decide which of the fields from $data[] you want to load 
          // to which fields in the database.
          $sql = "INSERT INTO ga (gaid,fe,fe1,timestamp) VALUES ('', '$key', '$value', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";
          $stmt = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

       } // endforeach
    } // endforeach
?>
```

if i used above code for insertion it display no error but it enter value in table `ga` like this

```
gaid      fe      fe1     timestamp
 1        0      array      -
```

the above code which i used for inserting in my table `ga`
the output of `print_r($asma);`

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => H Object ( 
            [Voltage] => 12 
            [Number] => 1 
            [Duration] => 3 
        ) 
        [1] => H Object ( 
            [Voltage] => 26 
            [Number] => 4 
            [Duration] => 8
        ) 
        [2] => H Object ( 
            [Voltage] => 26 
            [Number] => 4 
            [Duration] => 8 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => H Object ( 
            [Voltage] => 18 
            [Number] => 1 
            [Duration] => 4 
        ) 
        [1] => H Object ( 
            [Voltage] => 38 
            [Number] => 4 
            [Duration] => 10 
        ) 
        [2] => H Object ( 
            [Voltage] => 36 
            [Number] => 2 
            [Duration] => 8 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

i need to store all values in the database in above output 6 values.

this is table ga

```
gaid    fe    fe1    fe2   timestamep
```

Comment: plz people help me i need the solution

Comment: You have incorrect number of insert values (gaid, fe, timestamp) VALUES ('', $key, $val, timestamp). Notice 3 vs 4.  Try getting rid of the '', so it would be: `$sql = "INSERT INTO ga (gaid,fe,timestamp) VALUES ('$key', '$value','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";`

Comment: sir i need to store the values in database

Comment: sir it display the error at:$new_array = array_combine($asma,$asma);

Comment: error:Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\EMS3\ge.php on line 156

Comment: sir plz help me in this @chrislondon

Comment: It would be more useful to know what this array looks like `$asma`. Can you post a `print_r($asma)`

Comment: i edited my code so u can see what is $asma

Comment: @RiggsFolly plz help me in this

Comment: @RiggsFolly can u help in inserting the data instead of three rows in one row like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585754/how-to-insert-dynamic-array-into-the-database-in-php/17591931?noredirect=1#comment25608911_17591931 plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not help that you keep talking about `array1` in your description but I dont see anything called `array1` in your code.

But making the assumption that `array1 = $new_array` here is a suggestion.

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    //database connection
    //query
    /*
     * This achieves nothing other than adding an extra level of array
     *  Try removing it
     */ 
    //$new_array = array_combine($asma,$asma);

    foreach($asma as $key => $value) {

       foreach ( $value as $ind => $hObject ) {
          $q = "INSERT INTO ga (fe, fe1, f2, timestamp ) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, '%s' );
          $qs = sprintf( $q, $hObject->Voltage,$hObject->Duration, 
                             $hObject->Number, date("Y-m-d H:i:s") );
          $result = mysql_query($qs);
          if ( ! $result ) {
              die( 'Insert failed ' . mysql_errno() . ' ' . mysql_error() );                
          }

       } // endforeach
    } // endforeach
?>
```

Comment: its still display error at :Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\EMS3\ge.php on line 156     $new_array = array_combine($asma,$asma);

Comment: Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' this is also displayng

Comment: i will really appreciate if u help me in inserting in database

Comment: OK so please do a `print_r($asma)` BEFORE the `$new_array = (..)` line, and post it. Also do a `print_r($new_array)` and after the `$new_array = (..)` and post it.

Comment: Actually why are you doing this statement ` $new_array = array_combine($asma,$asma);`

Comment: print_r($asma) :Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => H Object ( [Voltage] => 18 [Number] => 1 [Duration] => 3 ) [1] => H Object ( [Voltage] => 38 [Number] => 4 [Duration] => 8 ) [2] => H Object ( [Voltage] => 36 [Number] => 2 [Duration] => 6 ) ) )

Comment: print_r($new_array):Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => H Object ( [Voltage] => 18 [Number] => 1 [Duration] => 3 ) [1] => H Object ( [Voltage] => 38 [Number] => 4 [Duration] => 8 ) [2] => H Object ( [Voltage] => 36 [Number] => 2 [Duration] => 6 ) ) )

Comment: how can i insert into database

Comment: What do you want to insert into the database. Your current statement makes no sense

Comment: i want to insert $asma values in database

Comment: Into which fields? So tell me what $data['??'] fields are to be put into what column names.

Comment: my columns are fe,fe1,f2 in which fe will contain voltage,fe1  will contain duration and f2 contain number in terms of values they store

Comment: Ok we are getting there... slowly. Better show me the schema for the ga table.

Comment: no sir its not inserting values in the database plzzzzzzzzzz help me

Comment: What is it doing? I have added some very simple error processing to the test after the insert. try that. What errors is it generating?

Comment: these are error:Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\EMS3\ge.php on line 152 , line 152 : $new_array = array_combine($asma,$asma);

Comment: and other error is : Fatal error: Cannot use object of type H as array in C:\wamp\www\EMS3\ge.php on line 173, line 173  $qs = sprintf( $q, $data['Voltage'], $data['Duration'],

Comment: Ok I reviewed all you answers and I have changed my answer above. Try that.

Comment: thanku so much sir its working:) me so glad thanks a lot relly appreciate your help