# How to insert dynamic array into the database in php?

Tags: php, html, arrays, phpmyadmin

i am working on dynamic array i need to insert these array in the database.when i insert dynamic array into the database instead of displaying in one row its cover three row.

coding for insertion

```
this is my array

$asma[]=GA::select($ga->population,'total',3);
```

this is  insertion query i need to insert the detail in six column as my output comprises of six values .

```
    $Voltage = array();
    $Duration = array();
    $Number = array();

    foreach($asma as $key => $value) 
    {

       foreach ( $value as $ind => $hObject ) 
       {
          $Voltage[] = $hObject->Voltage;
          $Duration[] = $hObject->Duration;
          $Number[] = $hObject->Number;               

    } }// endforeach
    for(i=0;i<row_count;i++)
    {


  $q = "INSERT INTO ga (fe, fe1, fe2,fe3,fe4,fe5,fe6,f7,f8, timestamp,username ) VALUES (%d, %d, %d,%d, %d, %d,%d, %d, %d, '%s' ,'$login_session')";
    $qs = sprintf( $q, $Voltage[$i],$Duration[$i],$Number[$i],

                       date("Y-m-d H:i:s") );
    $result = mysql_query($qs);
    if ( ! $result ) {
         die( 'Insert failed ' . mysql_errno() . ' ' . mysql_error() );                
    }}}
?>
```

i need to store six values in `one` row if user select `1` from the option. if user select `two` from the option then `two` rows cover in the database.
here is my output

```
Array
(
    [0] => H Object
        (
            [Voltage] => 18
            [Number] => 1
            [Duration] => 6
        )

    [1] => H Object
        (
            [Voltage] => 38
            [Number] => 4
            [Duration] => 14
        )

    [2] => H Object
        (
            [Voltage] => 38
            [Number] => 4
            [Duration] => 14
        )
```

it is store in the database like this

```
Volatge     Duration Number Volatge Duration Number Volatge Duration      Number
18           6       1       18      6        1      18        6        1
38          14       4       38      14       4      38       14        4
38          14       4       38      14       4      38       14        4
```

i need to store like this

```
 Volatge     Duration Number Volatge Duration Number Volatge Duration      Number
  18           6        1      38      4       14      38     14             4
```

plz help my in this

Comment: column name can't possible to be duplicate and try to store it vertically

Comment: column name is not duplicate in data base i need it horizontally column name in database is from fe,fe1,fe2,fe3,fe4,fe5,fe6,f7,f8

Comment: @Sundar help me in thsi

Comment: @Seean help me in this

Comment: Your for loop is not valid php `for(i=0;i<row_count;i++)`. each of those should have a `$` - `for($i=0;$i<$row_count;$i++)`. Also, your `sprintf` has the wrong amount of variables. In you `$q` you have 9 `%d`, but in `$qs` you only are giving 3. Where do you expect the other 6 to come from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your query out of the foreach loop. Here is one way to do it -

```
$Voltage = array();
$Duration = array();
$Number = array();

foreach($asma as $key => $value) 
{

   foreach ( $value as $ind => $hObject ) {
      $Voltage[] = $hObject->Voltage;
      $Duration[] = $hObject->Duration;
      $Number[] = $hObject->Number;               ,
   }

} // endforeach
$q = "INSERT INTO ga (fe, fe1, fe2,fe3,fe4,fe5,fe6,f7,f8, timestamp,username ) VALUES (%d, %d, %d,%d, %d, %d,%d, %d, %d, '%s' ,'$login_session')";
$qs = sprintf( $q, $Voltage[0],$Duration[0],$Number[0],
                   $Voltage[1],$Duration[1],$Number[1],
                   $Voltage[2],$Duration[2],$Number[2],
                   date("Y-m-d H:i:s") );
$result = mysql_query($qs);
if ( ! $result ) {
     die( 'Insert failed ' . mysql_errno() . ' ' . mysql_error() );                
}
```

---

**edit**

to add a second row, you can change it to something like this (note, I don't see where you are defining the select for 1/2, so I just put `$user_select`) -

```
$Voltage = array();
$Duration = array();
$Number = array();

foreach($asma as $key => $value) 
{

   foreach ( $value as $ind => $hObject ) {
      $Voltage[] = $hObject->Voltage;
      $Duration[] = $hObject->Duration;
      $Number[] = $hObject->Number;               ,
   }

} // endforeach
$q = "INSERT INTO ga (fe, fe1, fe2,fe3,fe4,fe5,fe6,f7,f8, timestamp,username ) VALUES (%d, %d, %d,%d, %d, %d,%d, %d, %d, '%s' ,'$login_session')";
$qs = sprintf( $q, $Voltage[0],$Duration[0],$Number[0],
                   $Voltage[1],$Duration[1],$Number[1],
                   $Voltage[2],$Duration[2],$Number[2],
                   date("Y-m-d H:i:s") );
if($user_select==2){  // if user select 2
    $q = ", (%d, %d, %d,%d, %d, %d,%d, %d, %d, '%s' ,'$login_session')";
    $qs = sprintf( $qs.$q, $Voltage[3],$Duration[3],$Number[3],
                             $Voltage[4],$Duration[4],$Number[4],
                             $Voltage[5],$Duration[5],$Number[5],
                             date("Y-m-d H:i:s") );
}
$result = mysql_query($qs);
if ( ! $result ) {
     die( 'Insert failed ' . mysql_errno() . ' ' . mysql_error() );                
}
```

---

**edit #2**
here is another version. Your for loop is not valid php `for(i=0;i<row_count;i++)`. each of those should have a `$` - `for($i=0;$i<$row_count;$i++)`. Also, your sprintf has the wrong amount of variables. In your `$q` you have 9 `%d`, but in `$qs` you only are giving 3. Where do you expect the other 6 to come from. In this I have changed you loop to increase by 3 - `for($i=0;$i<$row_count;$i+=3)`, and used `$Voltage[$i+1], $Duration[$i+1], $Number[$i+1], $Voltage[$i+2], $Duration[$i+2], $Number[$i+2],` to fill out the remaining 6 `%d`s

```
$Voltage = array();
$Duration = array();
$Number = array();

foreach($asma as $key => $value) 
{

   foreach ( $value as $ind => $hObject ) 
   {
      $Voltage[] = $hObject->Voltage;
      $Duration[] = $hObject->Duration;
      $Number[] = $hObject->Number;               

} }// endforeach
for($i=0;$i<$row_count;$i+=3)
{

  $q = "INSERT INTO ga (fe, fe1, fe2,fe3,fe4,fe5,fe6,f7,f8, timestamp,username ) VALUES (%d, %d, %d,%d, %d, %d,%d, %d, %d, '%s' ,'$login_session')";
  $qs = sprintf( $q, $Voltage[$i],$Duration[$i],$Number[$i],
                     $Voltage[$i+1],$Duration[$i+1],$Number[$i+1],
                     $Voltage[$i+2],$Duration[$i+3],$Number[$i+3],

                   date("Y-m-d H:i:s") );
  $result = mysql_query($qs);
  if ( ! $result ) {
     die( 'Insert failed ' . mysql_errno() . ' ' . mysql_error() );                
 }}}
?>
```

Comment: this work well in one input means when user select one from input available but if user select two from  the input then the two rows in the datbase have same data

Comment: I assumed that you would be able to figure out how to add the second row. Give me a few minutes and I will be back to give you an example.

Comment: I have edited with how to add the second row if user selects 2

Comment: you are mentioning the array name like 3 ,4,5 for user select 2 if it is the posiibility that user  select 3 or 4 or 5 as as input that mean different output come on different inputs how can i make it dynamic for that

Comment: the insertion in database depend upon the user inputs mean data inserted in number of rows.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You can change the 3,4,5 and even the 0,1,2. You can set them dynamically - ie. `$i` - base of what they want to repeat. You can do a lot of things, but it is difficult for me to help if I don't know what the user options/selects are.

Comment: it is basically on number of rooms user can enter any value in the textbox according his/hr depend after entering number of room above computation perform and result is generated in the form of array the data store in database depend upon the number of room that user eneter like if user enter 3 ,3 rows fill in the database that conatin 27 values from fe,fe,fe2,fe3,fe4,fe5,fe6,f7,f8 and vice versa with number of inputs increses

Comment: Okay, so what is your problem. The example(s) I gave can easily be adjusted to do all of that. What have you tried?

Comment: u again mention the lent of loop the lenght of loop it could be dyanmic it be 10 11 12 depent upon the user requriement

Comment: But how many `$hObject->Voltage;`,`$hObject->Duration;`, and `$hObject->Number;` are you inserting in each row? Your insert query shows 3 sets, but you are only binding 1 set in your `sprintf` - 9 != 3, so you either need to remove 6 `%d` from your query, or add 2 more sets of values to your `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
//code not tested check it

//Logic is changed instead of for looping many times
$data = array();

$j = 0;

foreach($asma as $key => $value)
{
$i = 0;

foreach ( $value as $ind => $hObject )
{
    if($i==0)
    {
        $data[$j]['fe'] = mysql_escape_string($hObject->Voltage);

    }else{

        $data[$j]['fe'.$i] = mysql_escape_string($hObject->Voltage);
    }

    $i++;

    $data[$j]['fe'.$i] = mysql_escape_string($hObject->Duration);
    $i++;

    $data[$j]['fe'.$i] = mysql_escape_string($hObject->Number);
    $i++;

}

$j++;

}// endforeach

//multiple array
 foreach($data as $array)
 {


 //unique array
//$array3 = array_merge($Voltage,$Duration,$Number);

$fields = implode(',',array_keys($array));

//if you want append any new field append it
$fields .= ','.'timestamp,username';

$vals = "'".implode("','",array_values($array))."'";

//if you want append any new values append it
$vals .= ",'".time()."','".$login_session."'";


$q = "INSERT INTO ga (".$fields.") VALUES(".$vals.")";

$result = mysql_query($q);
if ( ! $result ) {
    die( 'Insert failed ' . mysql_errno() . ' ' . mysql_error() );
}
 }
```

Comment: try to use mysqli extension instead of mysql

Comment: its only inserting 1 input values not other mean if user select 2 then only one row is inserted in the database not one n also timestamp is not according to session now

Comment: @ashy time and login session you modify according to your need or simply remove it if unnecessary

Comment: its not inserting data in the datbase

Comment: no error iam getting but it always insert first row in the database not inserting multiple rows

Comment: echo $q;  and list it what you getting.. we need to identify the query error. Some typo error exist before $qs is modified as $q

Comment: i am echo the values after inserting them into the table but still its display n insert one row only not multiple rows